# Can not find script file prerun_checks.vbs when installing postgresql 9.4.4 on Windows x64

Tags: windows-7, postgresql

I am getting the following error in the bitrock_installer log when I try to install postgresql (postgresql-9.4.4-3-windows x64):

```
Script output: 
Input Error: Can not find script file "C:\Users\administrator\Local Settings\postgresql_installer_71e39a3390\prerun_checks.vbs".
```

Here below is the full bitrock_installer log:

```
Log started 08/17/2015 at 13:17:43 
Preferred installation mode : qt 
Trying to init installer in mode qt 
Trying to init installer in mode qt 
Trying to init installer in mode win32 
Mode win32 successfully initialized 
Executing C:\Users\administrator\Local Settings/postgresql_installer_71e39a3390/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 0 

Script output: 
"test ok" 

Script stderr: 


Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 Data Directory. Setting variable iDataDirectory to empty value 
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value 
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 Service ID. Setting variable iServiceName to empty value 
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 Service Account. Setting variable iServiceAccount to empty value 
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 Super User. Setting variable iSuperuser to empty value 
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value 
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value 
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value 
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.4 DisableStackBuilder. Setting variable iDisableStackBuilder to empty value 
[13:17:47] Existing base directory: 
[13:17:47] Existing data directory: 
[13:17:47] Using branding: PostgreSQL 9.4 (x86) 
[13:17:47] Using Super User: postgres and Service Account: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService 
[13:17:47] Using Service Name: postgresql-9.4 
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Users\administrator\Local Settings\postgresql_installer_71e39a3390\prerun_checks.vbs" 
Script exit code: 1 

Script output: 
Input Error: Can not find script file "C:\Users\administrator\Local Settings\postgresql_installer_71e39a3390\prerun_checks.vbs". 

Script stderr: 
Program ended with an error exit code 

Error running cscript //NoLogo "C:\Users\administrator\Local Settings\postgresql_installer_71e39a3390\prerun_checks.vbs": Program ended with an error exit code
```

Any suggestions on what the issue can be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you move the script to a path that does not have spaces in it?

Comment: Hi albal, which script do you mean?

Comment: This script `C:\Users\administrator\Local Settings\postgresql_installer_71e39a3390\prerun_checks.vbs`

Comment: It does not exist in the folder, and everytime I press the installer for postgresql it will create a new folder (which also does not have prerun_checks.vbs in it). There is however another file in the created folder which is called temp_check_comspec.bat

Comment: To clarify, I have a `prerun_checks.vbs` file, but this is located under `C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local`. When I run the installer my log tells me it cannot find prerun_checks.vbs under  `C:\Users\administrator\ Local\postgresql_installer_[random identifier]`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changing the environment user variables "**TEMP**" and "**TMP**" from:

`C:\Users\administrator\Local Settings\Temp`

to

`C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Temp`

The reason behind this is that Microsoft changed certain symlinks. Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756982.aspx